# Converting old wordpress shortcode plugin to block

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, create-guten-block

I have an old wordpress plugin built to show latest posts of choice. The plugin uses a shortcode with options. Now I am converting the plugin little bit so that it can be used as a gutenberg block. I kept the php code intact and trying to create a block which will have some settings (right side setting box for block). I don't want to show the posts in block editor like other blocks instead I will just show the data in frontend. So in admin, nothing will be visible rather than a placeholder text and the settings. In plugin's *init.php* I have this code (Please ignore coding mistakes here, I just put some part to get the idea):

```
final class Dcposts {

function dcposts_block_assets() {
    register_block_type(
                'dc/block-dcposts', array(
                    'style'         => 'dcposts-style-css',
                    'editor_script' => 'dcposts-block-js',
                    'editor_style'  => 'dcposts-block-editor-css',
                    'render_callback' => array($this, 'mytest')
                )
            );
}

public function mytest($attributes) {
        return '[some_shortcode]'; // I will generate a dynamic shortcode with $attributes
    }
}
```

This works fine. If I add the block, it shows the posts front-end. But I get an error message in admin: 
"**Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.**"
while saving the page with the block; and also the shortcode executes in admin. How can I prevent this? Is this the right approach I am on? Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0):

The error message *"Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."* occurs when your `render_callback` function returns different content than the Gutenberg Edit() function. For dynamic blocks, [the save() function should return null](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#saving-attributes-via-serialization).

The [ServerSideRender](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-server-side-render/) block is ideal for migrating/integrating existing PHP functions into a Gutenberg block.

You are on the right path with registering your block `dc/block-dcposts` in PHP. Next, add a `ServerSideRender` component in the Edit function of your block declaration in JavaScript, eg:

index.js

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import ServerSideRender from '@wordpress/server-side-render';

/**
* Registering our block in JavaScript
*/
registerBlockType('dc/block-dcposts', {
    title: __('DCPosts', 'dc'),
    description: __(
        'What DCPosts does..',
        'dc'
    ),
    category: 'layout',
    icon: 'star-filled',
    edit: () => {
        return (
            <ServerSideRender
                block="dc/block-dcposts"
            />
        );
    },
    save: () => { return null } // Dynamic blocks should return null to avoid validation error.
});
```

plugin.php (simplified example)

```
function dc_block_dcposts($attributes){
    return '<div>Dynamically rendered content</div>';
}

function dc_block_dcposts_init(){
    register_block_type( 'dc/block-dcposts', array(
        'render_callback' => 'dc_block_dcposts',
    ) );
};

add_action( 'init', 'dc_block_dcposts_init' );
```

Once you have the basic setup working, the next step could be migrating any attributes your PHP function requires. The attributes need to be defined [in the block setup](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/create-block/attributes/) and then passed in via the [ServerSideRender component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-server-side-render/#usage-2) to be recieved by your PHP function.